# 20 hours Layovers at Heathrow and Dublin airports. Do I require transit visa for both?

Tags: transit-visas, airport-transfer, london, british-airways, dublin

I hold an Indian Passport.

I am traveling from Mumbai to Washington DC via the British Airways flight which has two layovers: 16 hours in London and 4 hours in Dublin. I possess an F-1 US student visa. I would be reaching London at 18:25 p.m. and would depart for Dublin at 6:30 a.m. the next day. Similarly, I would reach Dublin at 8:00 a.m. and depart for Washington DC at 12:00 p.m.

I would also need to change terminals at Heathrow from Terminal 5 to Terminal 2.

I wanted to know whether I would require a transit visa for both the places as I am not able to get proper information about the requirements from the official pages. Reading the pages only show that you can transit without a visa if you hold an itinerary to your destination and hold the visa for the US.

Please help me as I am confused and don't want to get in trouble at international airports.

Comment: You need to break it down into two different issues. 1. Do you need transit visa in UK and 2. Do you need transit visa in Dublin. Overall in your situation it appears you do not need a transit visa. I will defer answering to others with more knowledge.

Comment: For UK: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34106/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-if-i-need-a-transit-visa-for-a-layover-in-the-uk

Comment: For Dublin: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/56967/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-in-dublin-when-traveling-from-india-to-usa?rq=1

Comment: @user56513: They're actually interrelated, because of the Common Travel Area. If the OP were flying direct from London to the US, they would clearly fall under the Transit Without Visa scheme, but an UK-Irish connection (with is _to some extent_ handled like a domestic flight) tends to make things more complex. At least one plausible reading of the Visitor Rules would say that whether they qualify for TWOV in the UK depends on how Ireland would treat them at the next stop.

Comment: Also it appears you are not doing an airport transfer, just a layover. Transfer usually means exiting the airport, basically going through immigration controls.

Comment: @user56513 So, you mean that I can change terminals at Heathrow airport without going through the hassle of border control and immigration?

Comment: @YashSrivastava It's physically possible to change terminals at Heathrow without going through security, you're only allowed to do it if you're ticketed through (i.e. it's one ticket which includes both flights). As far as I'm aware there are no hotels airside so given you need to wait overnight that would not be a great option for you (although see https://www.sleepinginairports.net/sleep-guide/sleeping-in-london-heathrow-airport.htm ).